# What are the equivalent PC keyboard keys of the Xbox 360 game controller buttons shown on the screen?

Tags: pc, castle-crashers

The PC port of Castle Crashers shows Xbox 360 game controller buttons on its in-game messages and the UI. However, I'm playing with a mouse and a keyboard. This makes learning the controls a bit awkward.

[image]

What are the equivalent (default) PC keyboard keys and mouse buttons of the Xbox 360 game controller buttons shown on the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

| Function | Xbox 360 | PC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Move forward, back, left, right | **D-pad or Left Stick** | **Arrow Keys** |
| Heavy Attack | **Y** | <kbd>W</kbd> |
| Light Attack | **X** | <kbd>D</kbd> |
| Use Item | **B** | <kbd>A</kbd> |
| Jump | **A** | <kbd>Space</kbd> |
| Magic | **RT** | <kbd>Shift</kbd> |
| Item Select | **LB** | <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> |
| Pause | **Start** | <kbd>Esc</kbd> |
| Block | **LT** | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> |
| Eat | n/a | <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> |
| Ring Bell | n/a | <kbd>D</kbd> |
| Stats | n/a | <kbd>Tab</kbd> |
| Return Home | n/a | <kbd>H</kbd> |

---

Source: Control settings of the [Xbox 360 controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmpGB.jpg) and [PC keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWGs5.jpg).

[image: Xbox 360 controller]
[image: PC keyboard]